# Form data not inserting in Wordpress database even though hard coded data gets inserted

Tags: database, wordpress, forms, insert

I'm trying to build a form in Wordpress and inserting data from the form into the database. When I use hard coded data it works fine but if I change that to use variables from the form it is not inserting data at all.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: My Form Page
*/
?>
<?php
//user posted variables
$name = $_POST['message_name'];
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$message = $_POST['message_text'];
$human = $_POST['message_human'];
$selectedFood  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['selectedFood']) && is_array($_POST['selectedFood']) && count($_POST['selectedFood']) > 0){
    $selectedFood = implode(', ', $_POST['selectedFood']);
}
 //establish connection
if(empty($errorMessage)) 
        {
            $db = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
            if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
            mysql_select_db("xxx" ,$db);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_picnic_guest (name, yourname, moviename) VALUES ($name, $email, $message)"; 
            mysql_query($sql);


        }
function PrepSQL($value)
    {
        // Stripslashes
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        // Quote
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

        return($value);
    }


  //response generation function
  $response = "";
   //function to generate response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){
     global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";

    else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

  }
    //response messages
$not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
$missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
$email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
$message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
$message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";



//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Picnic Food from ".get_bloginfo('name');
$body =  "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message: $message\n Selected Food:\n $selectedFood";
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
if(!$human == 0){
  if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
  else {

    //validate email
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
else //email is valid
{
  //validate presence of name and message
if(empty($name) || empty($message)){
  my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
}
else //ready to go!
{
  $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, strip_tags($message), $headers);
if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!

else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
}

}

  }
}
else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>
<?php 
function clearform()
{
    document.getElementById("name").reset(); //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("email").reset(); //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("message").reset(); //don't forget to set the textbox ID
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <header class="entry-header">
              <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
              <?php the_content(); ?>

             <style type="text/css">
  .error{
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .success{
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: green;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  form span{
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="respond">
  <?php echo $response; ?>
  <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br><input id= "name" type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br><input id="email" type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Tea"><label for="type4">Tea</label><?php
if(isset($_POST['selectedFood']) && is_array($_POST['selectedFood']) && count($_POST['selectedFood']) > 0){ 
  $selectedFood = implode(', ', $_POST['selectedFood']);
    echo "   Chosen"; }
else { echo ""; }
?>  </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Bread"><label for="type1">Bread</label></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Cheese"><label for="type2">Cheese</label></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Cake"><label for="type3">Cake</label> </br>

    <p><label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br><textarea id="message" type="text" name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_human">Human Verification: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
    <p><input type="submit" />

</p>
  </form>

</div>


            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

          </article><!-- #post -->

      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wordpress default insert function for inserting values.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: My Form Page
*/
?>
<?php
//user posted variables
$name = $_POST['message_name'];
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$message = $_POST['message_text'];
$human = $_POST['message_human'];
$selectedFood  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['selectedFood']) && is_array($_POST['selectedFood']) && count($_POST['selectedFood']) > 0){
    $selectedFood = implode(', ', $_POST['selectedFood']);
}
 //establish connection
if(empty($errorMessage)) 
        {
            global $wpdb;
           $wpdb->insert('wp_picnic_guest',
               array('name'=>$name,
                    'yourname'=>$email,
                     'moviename'=>$message
                        )   );


        }
function PrepSQL($value)
    {
        // Stripslashes
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        // Quote
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

        return($value);
    }


  //response generation function
  $response = "";
   //function to generate response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){
     global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";

    else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

  }
    //response messages
$not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
$missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
$email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
$message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
$message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";



//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Picnic Food from ".get_bloginfo('name');
$body =  "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message: $message\n Selected Food:\n $selectedFood";
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
if(!$human == 0){
  if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
  else {

    //validate email
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
else //email is valid
{
  //validate presence of name and message
if(empty($name) || empty($message)){
  my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
}
else //ready to go!
{
  $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, strip_tags($message), $headers);
if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!

else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
}

}

  }
}
else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>
<?php 
function clearform()
{
    document.getElementById("name").reset(); //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("email").reset(); //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("message").reset(); //don't forget to set the textbox ID
}
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <header class="entry-header">
              <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
              <?php the_content(); ?>

             <style type="text/css">
  .error{
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .success{
    padding: 5px 9px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    color: green;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  form span{
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="respond">
  <?php echo $response; ?>
  <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br><input id= "name" type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br><input id="email" type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Tea"><label for="type4">Tea</label><?php
if(isset($_POST['selectedFood']) && is_array($_POST['selectedFood']) && count($_POST['selectedFood']) > 0){ 
  $selectedFood = implode(', ', $_POST['selectedFood']);
    echo "   Chosen"; }
else { echo ""; }
?>  </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Bread"><label for="type1">Bread</label></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Cheese"><label for="type2">Cheese</label></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFood[]" value="Cake"><label for="type3">Cake</label> </br>

    <p><label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br><textarea id="message" type="text" name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
    <p><label for="message_human">Human Verification: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" style="width: 60px;" name="message_human"> + 3 = 5</label></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
    <p><input type="submit" />

</p>
  </form>

</div>


            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

          </article><!-- #post -->

      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked 100% Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no needs for connecting database.It's already connected.
So remove code lines for connecting database.

Try with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_picnic_guest (name, yourname, moviename) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message')";
```